# I have made listview with checkbox but while scrolling listview more checkbox is select randomly and it does not hold their position

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have made `ListView` with `CheckBox` but while scrolling listview more `CheckBox` is select randomly and it does not hold their position. Please help me. thanks in advance

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.row1, parent, false);
    }
    Data item = this[position];
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.title).Text = item.nameview;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.reporter).Text = item.EmailIdview;
    checkbox = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkbox);          
    checkbox.Tag = item.nameview;
    checkbox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckedChangeListener(context, list, position));
    return view;
}

public class CheckedChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Data> list;
    private  int mPosition;

    public CheckedChangeListener(Activity context, List<Data> list, int mPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.mPosition = mPosition;
    }

    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked) {
        Group gr = new Group();                
        string name = buttonView.Tag.ToString();
        if (isChecked) {
            gr.checkboxSelected(name, isChecked);//list.ElementAt(mPosition)                    
        } else {                
            gr.setPosition(mPosition);                    
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: take holder class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use model class to hold the checked status of checkbox. As i can see yo have a model class called **Data**

you can add isChecked in **Data** model class like this,

```
public class Data {

    String name;
    boolean isChecked;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }
}
```

Now you have some sort of adapter class : **use view holder pattern**

you can set tag for checkbox.
I can give yo reference example for this follow the same you will get desired result.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public Activity context;

    public List<Data> list;

    public DataAdapter(Activity context, List<Data> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Holder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckedChangeListener());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);//important line
        holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).isChecked());
        return view;
    }

    private class CheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        public CheckedChangeListener() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            int position=(int) compoundButton.getTag();//important line
            list.get(position).setChecked(b);//important line
        }
    }

    public static class Holder {
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Happy coding `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Override this two methods inside of your Adapter:

```
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Their can be a no. of reasons for this problem.

Your adapter does not know how many type of views are their in your list. For that you can include these two functions in your adapter.

```
@Override public int getViewTypeCount() { return 1; }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Other reason can be that you are updating something in the list but not updating it in the database(model) you fetched it from.On scroll your list view will loose the info about the items scrolled away from the screen.It will load them again from the database you provided to it.So that database should have updated info. check this link for detail.

Not using else to all ifs in the adapter: As many if conditions you use in the adapter always give a else with it so that the adapter knows what to do.This is sometimes a reason for jumbling up of adapter items.

Not using viewholder pattern: This is also a well known reason for this issue. You should use viewholder pattern which ensures that the adapter does not draw the layout again and again.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of ListView's item view's reuse mechanism. You can change your `Data`'s source code like one of the answer said, or you can add a `List` field to your adapter to save each item's check state and restore when the relative item is shown.